# Am I creating a usable custom page variable properly here?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In one of my templates I'm attempting to be able to set the background color of a specific post via the liquid template at the top of a post. My template has this in it:

```
<style>
{% if page.style %}
  body {background-color: { { page.style.bgcolor }}}
{% endif %}
</style>
```

And then here's the liquid template from the post:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Post Name"
date:   2014-03-18 16:01:57
tags: game
style:
  bgcolor: green
image:
  feature: feature-image.png
---
```

Am I creating a custom variable properly, or is what I'm attempting not even possible?

This the result:

```
body {background-color: { { page.style.bgcolor }}}
```

Comment: What are the results when you access your resulting html page?

Comment: Sorry, should have added that into the question. There it is now.

Comment: Looks like your code did what you wrote. Are you ting to have page.style.bgcolor EVALUATED and the result entered?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have it evaluated and pull out what is after "bgcolor:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I was doing this correctly but it wouldn't parse because of the extra spaces between { {.

The fix involved simply changing

```
body {background-color: { { page.style.bgcolor }}}
```

To

```
body {background-color: {{page.style.bgcolor}} }
```

Comment: Why delete question is good and answer to. Just approve your own answer.

Comment: I will when I'm allowed (2 days apparently). Typically my stackoverflow experience is any non-complex question gets down voted... losing reputation for the person who asked it.